# Query to find max(RecordId) on Duplicate Record Items

Tags: soql

I want to find the AccountId that is most of times used as Duplicate Record Item. I tried

```
select id, count(RecordId)
from DuplicateRecordItem
group by RecordId
```

but i get

```
MALFORMED_QUERY: 
select id, count(RecordId)
                 ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:18
Grouped field should not be aggregated: RecordId
```

What is the correct query ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query should make the trick:

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), RecordId
FROM DuplicateRecordItem
GROUP BY RecordId
ORDER BY COUNT(Id) DESC
LIMIT 1
```